# php, mysql: want to make a shortcut for stmt query function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, return, connection

for query function I made this:

```html
function query($query){global $conn;
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){return false;};
    return  mysqli_query($conn, $query);}


function db($string){global $conn;
return mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST[$string] );}
```

I run it like this:

```html
query("UPDATE `item` 
        SET `name` = '".db('itemname_edit')."'
        , `type` = '".db('itemtype_edit')."'
        , `category` = '".db('itemcategory_edit')."'
        , `description` = '".db('descriptionitem_edit')."'
        , `updated_at` = CURRENT_TIME() 
         WHERE `item`.`id` = '".db('itemid_edit')."';
        ") )
```

I want to create another function with stmt phrase
something like (this part I dont know how to write it right)

```html
function queryStmt($query, $stmtFunction){global $conn;
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){return false;};
    $stmtFunction; ?????
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    return mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);}
```

that will run something like this

```html
queryStmt("UPDATE `item` 
        SET `name` = '?'
        , `type` = '?'
        , `category` = '?'
        , `description` = '?'
        , `updated_at` = ?
         WHERE `item`.`id` = '?';
        ") 
        ,mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", 
               db('itemname_edit')
               ,db('itemtype_edit')
               ,db('itemcategory_edit')
               ,db('descriptionitem_edit')
               ,CURRENT_TIME() 
               ,db('itemid_id')
               ) 
             )
```

How can I make and apply right the queryStmt function?

Comment: You need to start by learning basics of PHP and mysqli. However, I would recommend learning PDO instead of mysqli. Check out https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: 1. Do not escape parameters. 2. Placeholders are not strings and should not be enclosed in quotes. 3. `CURRENT_TIME()` is an SQL function and cannot be bound. 4. Stop checking for return values of `mysqli_stmt_prepare()` 5. Use OOP-style.

Comment: Dont do `global $conn;` either. If you are going to make a shorthand helper for db actions (which reduce the myriad of duplicate db action code), make it as a CLASS object and properly build everything you need into it. OR you could grab one that works already, like [Grumpy's PDO object](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO).